# jupyter lab rotating a 3D plot uses all CPUs

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab

I just did a fresh install of the latest linux Mint 21.3 "Virginia" Cinnamon based on Ubuntu 22.04. I've got a dedicated NVidia graphics card with the latest Nvidia drivers installed. I'm running AMD Ryzen 7 5800X and my NVidia graphics card is nothing exciting - it's a fanless 2GB card but this should be enough not to cause the problem that I'm facing. I am using the latest google chrome browser.

I've started to need to create interactive 3D plots. I use:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
%matplotlib ipympl
```

When manipulating the plot (e.g. rotating) **CPU** usage goes very high (80%) on all 16 CPUs (threads). I can also see GPU usage go up a bit (normally stays ~ 4% and goes up to 24%).

I feel I should not be seeing my CPU usage go up by much when rotating a plot. A video game has to rotate so many more objects that if my CPU went to 80% just by rotating a plot, it will have to go to 800% to play even the simplest of video games. I feel either my browser or jupyter kernel is not using the GPU.

I don't have a lot of experience with 3D plot rendering but this must be a common requirement/problem. **Any help or pointers will be greatly appreciated!**

Lastly, my browser GPU settings are below.

## Graphics Feature Status

- Canvas: Hardware accelerated
- Canvas out-of-process rasterization: Enabled
- Direct Rendering Display Compositor: Disabled
- Compositing: Hardware accelerated
- Multiple Raster Threads: Enabled
- OpenGL: Enabled
- Rasterization: Hardware accelerated
- Raw Draw: Disabled
- Skia Graphite: Disabled
- Video Decode: Hardware accelerated
- Video Encode: Software only. Hardware acceleration disabled
- Vulkan: Disabled
- WebGL: Hardware accelerated
- WebGL2: Hardware accelerated
- WebGPU: Disabled